# Is fission reaction considered natural or artificial?

Tags: nuclear-physics, terminology, history, nuclear-engineering

As I learned, nuclear fission doesn't occur without the control of a human made nuclear reactor, by hitting a neutron to a fissile isotope. Thus, the fission reaction is considedred as a part of 'ARTIFICIAL REACTIONS' category.

But, I've just noticed in a wikipedia article ([Natural nuclear fission reactor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_nuclear_fission_reactor)), that nuclear chain reactions had occurred on Earth about 2 billion years ago, what proves that fission existed naturally before.

Another additional question I was wondering is:
Is there any chance that a natural nuclear chain reaction can re-occur on Earth?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about semantics rather than physics.

Comment: Would you consider fire to be natural or artificial?

Comment: [*"the Gabon nuclear reactors are remarkable because they spontaneously began operating around two billion years ago, and they continued to operate in a stable manner for up to one million years.*"](http://blogs.scientificamerican.com/guest-blog/2011/07/13/natures-nuclear-reactors-the-2-billion-year-old-natural-fission-reactors-in-gabon-western-africa/)

Comment: @EmilioPisanty The fire is another whole story. But what I'm discussing now, is 'fission nuclear chain reactions'. Imagine if it stills active naturally, I think everything in the earth would be destroyed.

Comment: Your title mentions fusion, but you completely ignore that part in the question? There are most definitely natural fusion reactors, as every star is one.

Comment: Fire is much the same story, I think. Both are "things that can happen", as BySymmetry put it. Unless you can specify what you mean by "natural" and "artificial" to the point that the analogous choice for fire is trivial, it is completely pointless to try and do the same for more complicated phenomena. -1.

Comment: @YounesseBagachoul Natural fission reaction did occur naturally and it did not destroy anything but a number of uranium nuclei. Why do you think it would destroy "everything"?

Comment: @YounesseBagachoul Natural fission reactors do not burn fuel quickly. It would be less "everything on earth would be destroyed" and more ["There are some rocks, probably in the middle of nowhere, quick possibly deep underground, that are a little warmer and a little more radioactive than normal."](http://xkcd.com/683/)

Comment: @EmilioPisanty, I mean that fission nuclear chain reactions appeared spontaneously, seems to be 'natural'. But as I learned everytime in school, that Fission was an ARTIFICIAL phenomena.

Comment: And as we keep telling you, it is meaningless to continue discussing [unless you provide precise definitions of 'natural' and 'artificial'](http://abstrusegoose.com/215). What makes it impossible for a phenomenon to be both natural *and* artificial? Do you need to make an exception for fire? What about [dams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landslide_dam)?

Comment: That what I am asking for. I don't know if it's either natural or artificial or it may be both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't really a difference between "natural" or "artificial" reactions. All reactions are just "things that can happen". Some things only happen in certain circumstances, and those circumstances may be very unlikely to occur without being specifically engineered, but there is no reason in principle why they could not happen naturally.

There is evidence that there have been [natural fission reactors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_nuclear_fission_reactor) on earth and there is no reason in principle why it could not happen again, although I don't think we know of anywhere that looks likely to go critical in the near future and as the earths uranium radioactively decays to other elements it becomes less and less likely.

Answer (score 1):

For a fission chain reaction to spontaneously happen in uranium there are some requirements to be fulfilled. 
A)  there should be at least 4% U-235 in the mix of uranium isotopes. 
B) there should be a moderator to decrease the energy of the neutrons which result from the fission of a uranium core.

2 billion years ago the percentage of U-235 was large enough to sustain a chain reaction. Furthermore there was water seeping in the uranium which acted as a moderator. The heat from the fission turned the water into steam and stopped the chain reaction. This went on and off. So there was no continuous chain reaction for a billion years. 
Since then radioactive decay decreased the percentage of U-235 as it's half life is shorter than that of U-238. so no fission chain reaction will spontaneously occur in the earth crust.